# Sum every second column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

I'm looking to try and sum every second column. For example I need to add column f4+h4+j4 etc... with the answers going into column B4. Also need the columns e4+g4+i4+K4 etc.... with the answers going in to column A4.

Answer (score 3):

If the **L** and **A** column headers in row 3 are consistent then the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) should do this easily.

In A4 as,

```
=SUMIF($E$3:$ZZ$3, A$3, $E4:$ZZ4)
```

Fill both right and down.

Comment: Hi thank you for that. So if I adjust for the row, eg e4,e5,e6 etc...then fill this in columns A and B, This will add the corresponding columns headed L and A into the correct cell in columns A and B?

Comment: The formula goes into A4 as-is then copy that to B4 and fill A4:B4 down.